# Начальная точки из цента экрана JS

Tags: javascript

Суть вопроса кроется в изменении скрипта, создающего точки и анимацию заднего фона. В настоящий момент первая точка устанавливается от левого верхнего края экрана и выстраивает точки до противоположных краев. Проблема в том, что логотип в центре экрана и на его углах должно быть 4 точки. Картинка для понимания проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, отправная точка должна быть из центра видимой области экрана со смещением влево вверх на половину значения "pointDistance" и уже от этой точки расходиться к краям экрана.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

```js
(function() {

    var width, height, canvas, ctx, points, target, animateHeader = true;
    var pointDistance   = 85;
    var pointRadius     = 2;
    var raf;

    // Main
    initHeader();
    initAnimation();
    addListeners();

    function initHeader() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = Math.max(
    document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
  );
        target = {};

        canvas = document.getElementById('background-canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // create points
        initPoints();
    }

    // Event handling
    function addListeners() {
        if(!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    }

    function initAnimation() {
        animate();
    }

    function animate() {
        if(animateHeader) {
            drawPoints();
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function mouseMove(e) {
        var posx = posy = 0;
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            posx = e.pageX;
            posy = e.pageY;
        }
        else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
            posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        target.x = posx;
        target.y = posy;
    }

    function resize() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = Math.max(
    document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
  );
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        for(var i in points) {
            TweenLite.killTweensOf(points[i]);
        }

        initPoints();
    }

    function initPoints(){
        // create points
        points = [];
        for(var x = 0; x <= width/pointDistance; x++) {
            for(var y = 0; y < height/pointDistance; y++) {
                var px = x*pointDistance;
                var py = y*pointDistance;
                var p = {x: px, originX: px, y: py, originY: py };
                points.push(p);
            }
        }

        // for each point find the 5 closest points
        for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            var closest = [];
            var p1 = points[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
                var p2 = points[j]
                if(!(p1 == p2)) {
                    var placed = false;
                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(closest[k] == undefined) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(getDistance(p1, p2) < getDistance(p1, closest[k])) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            p1.closest = closest;
        }

        // assign a circle to each point
        for(var i in points) {
            var c = new Circle(points[i], pointRadius, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)');
            points[i].circle = c;
        }
    }

    function drawPoints(){

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);

        for(var i in points) {
            if(target){
                if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 4000) {
                    points[i].opacity = 0.3;
                    points[i].circle.opacity = 1;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 20000) {
                    points[i].opacity = 0.2;
                    points[i].circle.opacity = 1;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 40000) {
                    points[i].opacity = 0.1;
                    points[i].circle.opacity = 0.8;
                } else {
                    points[i].opacity = 0;
                    points[i].circle.opacity = 0.7;
                }
            }

            points[i].circle.color = 'rgba(180,180,180,1)';

            drawLines(points[i]);
            points[i].circle.draw();
        }
    }

    function shiftPoint(p) {
        TweenLite.to(p, 1+1*Math.random(), {x:p.originX+Math.random()*(pointDistance/2),
            y: p.originY+Math.random()*(pointDistance/2), ease:Circ.easeInOut,
            onComplete: function() {
                shiftPoint(p);
            }});
    }

    function drawLines(p) {
        if(target){
            for(var i in p.closest) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
                ctx.lineTo(p.closest[i].x, p.closest[i].y);
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(110,110,110,'+p.opacity+')';
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
    }

    function Circle(pos,rad,color) {
        var _this = this;

        // constructor
        (function() {
            _this.pos = pos || null;
            _this.radius = rad || null;
            _this.color = color || null;
        })();

        this.draw = function() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(_this.pos.x, _this.pos.y, _this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(50,50,50,'+_this.opacity+')';
            ctx.fill();
        };
    }


    // Util
    function getDistance(p1, p2) {
        return Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2);
    }
    

})();
```

```css
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font: inherit;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

audio,
canvas,
video {
 display: inline-block;
}
audio:not([controls]) {
 display: none;
 height: 0;
}
[hidden],
template {
 display: none;
}
html {
 line-height: 1;
}

abbr[title] {
 border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
b,
strong {
 font-weight: bold;
}
dfn {
 font-style: italic;
}
mark {
 background: #ff0;
 color: #000;
}
code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
 font-size: 1em;
}
pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap;
}
q {
 quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019";
}
small {
 font-size: 80%;
}
sub,
sup {
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 font-size: 75%;
 line-height: 0;
}
sup {
 top: -0.5em;
}
sub {
 bottom: -0.25em;
}
img {
 border: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
}
svg:not(:root) {
 overflow: hidden;
}
figure {
 margin: 0;
}
fieldset {
 margin: 0 2px;
 padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
 border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
legend {
 padding: 0;
 border: 0; 
}

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-appearance: button;
}
button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
 cursor: default;
}
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
 padding: 0;
}
input[type="search"] {
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}
textarea {
 overflow: auto;
 vertical-align: top;
}
div { 
 border: 0px; 
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

table {
 border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td {
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: normal;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

q, blockquote {
 quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
 content: "";
 content: none;
}

a img {
 border: none;
}

/*------ General style ------*/
body {
 font-family: 'MagistralC', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 line-height: 1.2;
 background-color: #000;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
 overflow-x: hidden;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

hr {
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 border: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
 margin: .4em 0;
 padding: 0;
}

img {
 vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
 border: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
textarea {
 resize: vertical;
}
blockquote {
 margin: 30px 0px 30px 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 position: relative;
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: 300;
 border-left: 2px solid #39F;
}
a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.with-clear:after,
.clr:after {
 display: table;
 clear: both;
 content: '';
}

footer .middle,
header .middle {
 padding: 0 30px;
}

.middle {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1260px;
 padding: 60px 30px;
 background: #000;
}

{
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px
}

.img {
 transition:All 0.36s ease;
 -webkit-transition:All 0.36s ease;
 -moz-transition:All 0.36s ease;
 -o-transition:All 0.36s ease;
}
.img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 104%;
 height: 104%;
 left: -2%;
 top: -1%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
}
.valign-middle {
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -ms-flex-align: center;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#background-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.logo-block {
width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  line-height: 85px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
     <title>EM</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <main>
   <div class="valign-middle">
    <div class="logo-block">Logo</div>
   </div>
  </main>
     <canvas id="background-canvas"></canvas>
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
     <script src="js/points.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. вычисли смещение offsetX и offsetY, на которое должна сместиться точка ближайшая к углу логотипа, так чтоб она попала точно на его угол. 2. вставь это смещение в функцию `initPoints` `var px = x*pointDistance + offsetX` и `var py = y*pointDistance + offsetY`

Comment: Саму точку сместить не проблема. У нас есть расстояние между точками pointDistance, его разделить пополам и задать смещение. Проблема в том, чтоб установить первую точку в центр экрана и размножить остальные точки из центра до края экрана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно рассчитать на сколько отличается позиция центральной клетки сетки и сместить каждую клетку на необходимую величину, в этом случае центральный квадрат совпадет с логотипом.

Рассчитать смещение можно например по следующей формуле:

```
var logo = document.querySelector('.logo-block');
var shiftX = pointDistance + logo.offsetLeft - Math.ceil(width / pointDistance/2)*pointDistance;
var shiftY = pointDistance + logo.offsetTop - Math.ceil(height / pointDistance/2)*pointDistance;
```

Пример:

```js
(function() {

  var width, height, canvas, ctx, points, target, animateHeader = true;
  var pointDistance = 85;
  var pointRadius = 2;
  var raf;

  // Main
  initHeader();
  initAnimation();
  addListeners();

  function initHeader() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = Math.max(
      document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
      document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
      document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
    target = {};

    canvas = document.getElementById('background-canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // create points
    initPoints();
  }

  // Event handling
  function addListeners() {
    if (!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
  }

  function initAnimation() {
    animate();
  }

  function animate() {
    if (animateHeader) {
      drawPoints();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

  function mouseMove(e) {
    var posx = posy = 0;
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
      posx = e.pageX;
      posy = e.pageY;
    } else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
      posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    target.x = posx;
    target.y = posy;
  }

  function resize() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = Math.max(
      document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
      document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
      document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    for (var i in points) {
      TweenLite.killTweensOf(points[i]);
    }

    initPoints();
  }

  function initPoints() {

    var logo = document.querySelector('.logo-block');
    var shiftX = pointDistance + logo.offsetLeft - Math.ceil(width / pointDistance/2)*pointDistance;
    var shiftY = pointDistance + logo.offsetTop - Math.ceil(height / pointDistance/2)*pointDistance;

    // create points
    points = [];
    for (var x = 0; x <= width / pointDistance; x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < height / pointDistance; y++) {
        var px = x * pointDistance + shiftX;
        var py = y * pointDistance + shiftY;
        var p = {
          x: px,
          originX: px,
          y: py,
          originY: py
        };
        points.push(p);
      }
    }
    // for each point find the 5 closest points
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      var closest = [];
      var p1 = points[i];
      for (var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
        var p2 = points[j]
        if (!(p1 == p2)) {
          var placed = false;
          for (var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            if (!placed) {
              if (closest[k] == undefined) {
                closest[k] = p2;
                placed = true;
              }
            }
          }

          for (var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            if (!placed) {
              if (getDistance(p1, p2) < getDistance(p1, closest[k])) {
                closest[k] = p2;
                placed = true;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      p1.closest = closest;
    }

    // assign a circle to each point
    for (var i in points) {
      var c = new Circle(points[i], pointRadius, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)');
      points[i].circle = c;
    }
  }

  function drawPoints() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    for (var i in points) {
      if (target) {
        if (Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 4000) {
          points[i].opacity = 0.3;
          points[i].circle.opacity = 1;
        } else if (Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 20000) {
          points[i].opacity = 0.2;
          points[i].circle.opacity = 1;
        } else if (Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 40000) {
          points[i].opacity = 0.1;
          points[i].circle.opacity = 0.8;
        } else {
          points[i].opacity = 0;
          points[i].circle.opacity = 0.7;
        }
      }

      points[i].circle.color = 'rgba(180,180,180,1)';

      drawLines(points[i]);
      points[i].circle.draw();
    }
  }

  function shiftPoint(p) {
    TweenLite.to(p, 1 + 1 * Math.random(), {
      x: p.originX + Math.random() * (pointDistance / 2),
      y: p.originY + Math.random() * (pointDistance / 2),
      ease: Circ.easeInOut,
      onComplete: function() {
        shiftPoint(p);
      }
    });
  }

  function drawLines(p) {
    if (target) {
      for (var i in p.closest) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        ctx.lineTo(p.closest[i].x, p.closest[i].y);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(110,110,110,' + p.opacity + ')';
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    }
  }

  function Circle(pos, rad, color) {
    var _this = this;

    // constructor
    (function() {
      _this.pos = pos || null;
      _this.radius = rad || null;
      _this.color = color || null;
    })();

    this.draw = function() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(_this.pos.x, _this.pos.y, _this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(50,50,50,' + _this.opacity + ')';
      ctx.fill();
    };
  }


  // Util
  function getDistance(p1, p2) {
    return Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2);
  }


})();
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
}
audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}
[hidden],
template {
  display: none;
}
html {
  line-height: 1;
}
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}
mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}
code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-size: 1em;
}
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
q {
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}
small {
  font-size: 80%;
}
sub,
sup {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}
img {
  border: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
fieldset {
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
legend {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}
button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  padding: 0;
}
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div {
  border: 0px;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
caption,
th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
q,
blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
q:before,
q:after,
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}
a img {
  border: none;
}
/*------ General style ------*/

body {
  font-family: 'MagistralC', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  background-color: #000;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
hr {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
  margin: .4em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}
blockquote {
  margin: 30px 0px 30px 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-left: 2px solid #39F;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.with-clear:after,
.clr:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
footer .middle,
header .middle {
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1260px;
  padding: 60px 30px;
  background: #000;
}
{
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px
}
.img {
  transition: All 0.36s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.36s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.36s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.36s ease;
}
.img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 104%;
  height: 104%;
  left: -2%;
  top: -1%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.valign-middle {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
#background-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.logo-block {
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  line-height: 85px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="valign-middle">
    <div class="logo-block">Logo</div>
  </div>
</main>
<canvas id="background-canvas"></canvas>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Это именно то, что было нужно. Осталось справится с задачей, чтоб точки дорисовывались за пределами экрана и линии соединяющие эти точки не сбивались в одну плотную линию с правой стороны экрана. Думаю, с этим делом я справлюсь. Премного благодарен за подсказку и работающий пример.